# Anchoring Heuristic: a type of heuristic or the mechanism of functioning of heuristics?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, decision-making, bias, problem-solving

**Heuristic** is a mental shortcut that helps us to make decisions and judgments quickly, without spending time analyizing any aspect of reality.

There are several different categories of heuristics, three of them are:

- [Availability heuristic](https://publicwiki-01.fraunhofer.de/CIPedia/index.php/Psychological_Heuristics) involves making decisions based upon how easy it is to bring something to mind
- [The representativeness heuristic](https://publicwiki-01.fraunhofer.de/CIPedia/index.php/Psychological_Heuristics) involves making decisions by comparing the present situation to the most representative mental prototype
- [Base-rate heuristic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nSFHFfevfms) is a mental shortcut which helps us to make decisions based on probability

I've read another type of heuristic: [Anchoring Heuristic](https://www.alleydog.com/glossary/definition.php?term=Anchoring%20Heuristic) that refers to the human tendency to accept and rely on the first piece of information received. I think that every kind of Heuristic uses an anchor to make decisions...

### The point is: which is the difference among Anchoring Heuristic and the other types of heuristic?

I mean, to use an information as an anchor, is the mechanism of heuristic in general, isn't it?